# Notation on chart of the isotopes

Tags: nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, radiation, radioactivity

I recently purchased a complete chart of the isotopes,

(this one: https://shop.marktdienste.de/shoppages/produktuebersicht.aspx )

and have it on the wall next to me in work. The different coloured squares indicate what mode/s of decay an isotope naturally follows (unless it's stable; then it's a Black square). I understand all of it apart from one, which appears not to be explained. The purple square is labelled "ce".

My question is whether ce stands for carbon emission (I understand carbon emission can be considered a form of decay: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_decay) or coulomb excitation, or something else. The chart doesn't say, and both seem valid. My problem is that coulomb excitation isn't to my mind really a form of decay, and (as seen above) the "carbon emission" appears to be more commonly referred to as Cluster decay.

Comment: The image in the link is not of a sufficiently good resolution. If you can upload a photo of the square in question, we may be able to find out what it actually is.

Comment: WHy don't you contact the manufacturer and ask what $ce$ means (or if you're lucky it'll be in the fine print in one corner.

Comment: I have no way of uploading a photo here. It is simply described as "ce", a few of the elements shown as decaying via that mode are Pu-238, Pu-236 and Cm-242, all with <5% braching ratio for this decay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've cross checked it with some known isotopes which decay by Cluster Decay. It would appear to be that. I guess it stands for Cluster Emission.

Comment: Yep, you've got it right.